# APK How to use Android Bundle for fix GooglePlay Error

Tags: python, android, kivy, bundle

I'm just finished my coding and trying to upload to Google Play. Actually it's hard to upload just like coding:) So, I had to learn something about SDK and architect. I figured out how to fix'em and use. But at the end, when I'm trying to upload on GooglePlay, I'm getting this error.

***ERROR (Actually warning):***

```
Unoptimized APK Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.
```

I didn't see any "pass" button or smt. Like that for this ***WARNING***. So I think I have to fix that first.

I checked websites for solution but couldn't find anything for non coding on Android Studio apks. I mean, I coded this apk on PyCharm then created with buildozer after signed by keytool. The main question is, ***how can I generate signed bundle apk on Android Studio, with my created APK or coded .py files.***

Comment: did you solved this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Have you found a solution for this question until now?

Answer (score 2):

I never built an Android app in this way but I understand your problem [and your frustration]

I gave a look around and I found [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build):

> If you don't want to use Android Studio or Gradle tasks to build
> bundles — **for example, if you use a custom build toolchain** — you
> can use bundletool from the command line to build an app bundle from
> pre-compiled code and resources. If you haven't already done so,
> download bundletool from the GitHub repository

Comment: Thanks for answering .Im really glad to hear new ideas but there is a few problem about this bundletool. Page saying, ***You can build apks from bundle to apks*** Its meaning => (_my_app.aab_ to _my_app.apks_) .Also this documentation for only JAVA coding.I think i didn't report clearly.Im trying to make APK file from ***PYTHON CODING(_Kivy_)***.Actually i dont know , is that working for Python coding. If so , how can i create "my_app.aab" file from .py and .kv file.
So i have to ask same question from diffrent way :)
***How can i convert my _.py,.kv and other files_ to my_app.aab file***.

Comment: And im wondering sir , Are you coding apks with Java coding ? If you are using python and kivy lib. , how do you creating apks , with which build tool.Because i think i can't create apk on Android Studio with my python file.And when i try to build as python kivy official documentation says ,im facing like this warning and cannot upload my apk successfully. 
As you see im newbie :) 

If anyone can , can you inform me in detail about Python-APK-GooglePlay upload ways and documentations. Im afraid of , i almost leave python coding for create Applications ...

Comment: ciao, from [bundletool page](https://github.com/google/bundletool): "Build an Android App Bundle from pre-compiled modules of a project", so looks like you can use bundletool to build an .aab. The title of the section that I linked in the answer says "Build an app bundle using bundletool" too. [This section](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#build_your_app_bundle_using_bundletool) is even clearer: here `bundletool build-bundle --modules=base.zip --output=mybundle.aab` the app bundle is an output. I would at least try to follow this page before giving up. Good luck!

Comment: Hi , i missed this part :) But when i try to build my **.aab** file i get this : 

**Error: Module 'myapk' is missing mandatory file 'manifest/AndroidManifest.xml'.**

And then when i include AndroidManifest.xml from my apk which built with buildozer , i get new errors like : 

**Error reading module zip file 'myapk.zip'.**

Thanks for answering and trying buddy but it looks like useless for python ;(

Comment: Hi, any updates for this solution? Did you manage to handle the mentioned errors?

Comment: This might be the upstream issue: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2084